# Are these claims about tax paid in the 2017-2018 Australian tax year accurate?

Tags: australia, taxes

On December 14, 2019, the [Australian Greens](https://greens.org.au) posted a claim to their [Facebook feed](https://www.facebook.com/Australian.Greens/) about taxes paid by individuals and various entities.

The claim is in the image on this page, but essentially the claims are:

- That the following organisations paid 0 tax:

  - Sydney airport
  - Transurban
  - Pratt holding visy recycling
- These types of people paid tax:

  - Baggage handler: $7,872
  - Nurse earning $58,000 paid $10,397
  - Factory worker: $7,685

[image: Claims about amount paid]

Comment: Companies generally pay taxes on profits not turnover. It is entirely possible that all three companies have made a loss.

Comment: @PaulJohnson As a non native speaker: what does the word “income” used on the sign mean for companies?

Comment: It means the amount of money that they have taken in, also known as "revenue". From this they will pay rent, wages, buy stock etc. These are their costs. Very roughly, profit = income - costs. https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/profit.asp

Comment: @HartmutBraun On the other hand, this page says different. https://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/income.asp

Comment: @PaulJohnson thanks for pointing at both possibilities.

Comment: I've just been digging through the Sydney Airport annual report. It shows revenue as A$1,584.9M, which is pretty close to the $1.55B in the graphic, so they are calling revenue "income". Page 92 of the report shows a charge for income tax of 62.5M, so it looks like they are paying quite a lot of tax. However P122-124 talks about the airport being part of a larger structure for tax purposes, and that larger structure has made an overall loss, so that (if I understand correctly) has swallowed up the Sydney Airport taxes.

Comment: That seems weird. One company can't reclaim tax paid by another company, even if they own it. Could you link to the report?

Comment: The comment making reference to GST makes this very disingenuous, since the graphic only refers to company and income taxes. If we are bringing other taxes into it, these companies are probably all paying payroll tax, and possibly land tax as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Greens actually included a link to references, including original data from the Australian Tax Office (there were a lot of companies that paid zero tax) and analysis from a think tank (Australia Institute from memory). This is also a comment on the larger problem with companies dodging tax with creative accounting.

Comment: @DJClayworth I think the logic is like this: suppose I have two shops, one makes a loss and the other a profit. Overall I make a small loss, so I pay no tax. I split the two shops into separate businesses to protect the profitable one, but now I have to pay tax on the the profitable one. By linking the two for tax purposes I can still protect the profitable shop without being penalised by the tax man.

Comment: @DJClayworth Link is: https://www.sydneyairport.com.au/investor/investors-centre/reports/annual-reports